# Array in POST request with Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to send array to PHP script, but i can't detect this array on server side. I create php script that prints all REQUEST array. And for this code:

```
 let mapDict = [ "var1":"First", "var2":"Second"]

    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(mapDict, options: [])


        // create post request
        let url = NSURL(string: myURL)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData



        let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){

            data,response,error in

            if error != nil{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }


            let newData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(newData)

        }

        task.resume()
    }
    catch {
        print (error)
    }
```

In Xcode console I receive

```
Optional(Array
(
    [{"var1":"First","var2":"Second"}] => 
)
```

What am i doing wrong?

p.s. if i add .PrettyPrinted i receive:

```
Optional(Array
(
[{
__"var1"_:_"First",
__"var2"_:_"Second"
}] => 
)
```

And i don't know - where are this "_:_" came from?

Answer (score 1):

The php won't auto recognize that it's a json string

add this lines:

```
request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

allowing the PHP know it's a json string

Comment: it returns empty array if i add this code after request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

Comment: @moonvader What swift version are you using? I think you should check how does your php gets the data, it has to know that it's JSON

Comment: I use Swift 2. Maybe array can be sent without JSON?